# Basic question about uniform distribution and probability

Tags: probability

I have a question:

a) It seems to me intuitively that if $X\sim U[0,1)$ then $Y=aX-\lfloor aX\rfloor$ where $a\geq2$ integer also follows $U[0,1)$. Is that correct?

Comment: I think $a$ needs to be an integer.

Comment: Right, edited in. I was sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

To prove (a), it suffices that for a positive integer $a$, we can partition the support of $X$ as $$X \in [0,1) = \bigcup_{j=1}^a m_j, \quad m_j = \left[\frac{j-1}{a}, \frac{j}{a}\right).$$  Then it is trivial to see that $Y$ conditioned on $X \in m_j$ for each such $j$ is independent of $j$; thus if the density of $X \mid X \in [0,1/a)$ is uniform (which it is), then $Y$ is uniform.